# Changing the value of row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database column Model has 2000+ data

```
Model
------
EH2
EF
F3
RM
RX
RX2
R3
....
```

I want to make it like:

```
Model
---------
Primo EH2
Primo EF
Primo F3
....
```

I have tried:

```
update Table
set Model = REPLACE(Model,' ','Primo EF2')
```

to replace all EF,EF2 etc with Primo prefix(Primo EF,Primo EF2 etc)

I short i want to add Primo before all model
but it did not work.

Comment: What about this: `UPDATE Table SET Model = 'Primo EF2'`?

Comment: why no use the UI method, right click the table, edit top 200 rows the add a where clause to find the record you want?

Comment: `REPLACE(Model, Model, 'Primo ' + Model)` to replace all with `Primo` prefix ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace **all models** (!) to `PRIMO`+Model you can run the following code:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Model = N'Primo '+Model
```

If you want to set Primo just to **a specific list of models** try this instead:

```
UPDATE yt
SET Model = N'Primo '+Model
FROM yourTable yt
WHERE yt.Model IN(N'EF',N'EF2')
```

Comment: Well no problem. :-) Just edited the answer and highlighted the cases where to use a specific command. Just in case that someone runs the wrong command and crashes his database table. :-D

Answer (score 3):

`REPLACE(Model,' ','Primo EF2')` does not replace anything. There is no `' '` in your data.

Use

```
update Table set Model='Primo EH2' WHERE Model='EH2'
```

**UPDATE** regarding your new specification:

Use

`update Table set Model = 'Primo ' + Model`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that directly using

```
update Table
set Model ='Primo EF2' where Model = 'EH2'
```

Where ever the query find the column value as `EH2` it will replace it by `Primo EF2`